# ssh -X warning: X11 forwarding request failed on channel 0

Tags: linux, macos, ssh, xorg

When I run `ssh -X my_host` I get the error:
"X11 forwarding request failed on channel 0". (`ssh -Y my_host` gives the same error)

My host is a Gentoo Linux machine and my client is a macOS Catalina.
Both host and client have `xauth` installed.
The client has XQuartz-2.7.11 installed.

I have added the lines `ForwardX11 yes` and `X11UseLocalhost no` to the /etc/ssh/ssh_config file on the host, but that did not help.

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Possibly relevant information:

1. `xauth list $DISPLAY` gives no output on host nor on client.
2. I have added `XAuthLocation /opt/X11/bin/xauth`,  `ForwardX11Trusted yes` and `ForwardX11 yes` in the ".ssh/config" file of the client.

Edit:
the last lines of `ssh -vvvX my_host` are:

```
Authenticated to ******.
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: exec
debug3: receive packet: type 80
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug3: receive packet: type 4
debug1: Remote: /home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys:1: key options: agent-forwarding port-forwarding pty user-rc x11-forwarding
debug3: receive packet: type 4
debug1: Remote: /home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys:1: key options: agent-forwarding port-forwarding pty user-rc x11-forwarding
debug3: receive packet: type 91
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback start
debug2: x11_get_proto: /opt/X11/bin/xauth  list /private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.MRsK0ea50W/org.macosforge.xquartz:0 2>/dev/null
debug1: Requesting X11 forwarding with authentication spoofing.
debug2: channel 0: request x11-req confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: ssh_packet_set_tos: set IP_TOS 0x48
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug1: Sending environment.
debug3: Ignored env CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV
debug3: Ignored env CONDA_EXE
debug3: Ignored env CONDA_PREFIX
debug3: Ignored env CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER
debug3: Ignored env CONDA_PYTHON_EXE
debug3: Ignored env CONDA_SHLVL
debug3: Ignored env DISPLAY
debug3: Ignored env HOME
debug3: Ignored env JAVA_HOME
debug1: Sending env LC_CTYPE = UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug3: Ignored env LOGNAME
debug3: Ignored env LaunchInstanceID
debug3: Ignored env PATH
debug3: Ignored env PWD
debug3: Ignored env SECURITYSESSIONID
debug3: Ignored env SHELL
debug3: Ignored env SHLVL
debug3: Ignored env SSH_AUTH_SOCK
debug3: Ignored env TERM
debug3: Ignored env TERM_PROGRAM
debug3: Ignored env TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION
debug3: Ignored env TERM_SESSION_ID
debug3: Ignored env TMPDIR
debug3: Ignored env USER
debug3: Ignored env XPC_FLAGS
debug3: Ignored env XPC_SERVICE_NAME
debug3: Ignored env _CE_CONDA
debug3: Ignored env _CE_M
debug3: Ignored env __CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug3: receive packet: type 100
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 100 id 0
X11 forwarding request failed on channel 0
debug3: receive packet: type 99
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: PTY allocation request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug3: receive packet: type 99
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: shell request accepted on channel 0
```

log of host:

```
Aug 31 15:44:52 Jimmy sshd[12245]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=****  user=root
Aug 31 15:44:52 Jimmy sshd[12245]: pam_faillock(sshd:auth): Error opening the tally file for root: No such file or directory
Aug 31 15:44:53 Jimmy sshd[12026]: error: PAM: Authentication failure for root from ****
Aug 31 15:44:54 Jimmy sshd[12247]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=****  user=root
Aug 31 15:44:54 Jimmy sshd[12247]: pam_faillock(sshd:auth): Error opening the tally file for root: No such file or directory
Aug 31 15:44:56 Jimmy sshd[12026]: error: PAM: Authentication failure for root from ****
Aug 31 15:44:56 Jimmy sshd[12248]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=****  user=root
Aug 31 15:44:56 Jimmy sshd[12248]: pam_faillock(sshd:auth): Error opening the tally file for root: No such file or directory
Aug 31 15:44:58 Jimmy sshd[12026]: error: PAM: Authentication failure for root from ****
Aug 31 15:44:58 Jimmy sshd[12026]: Received disconnect from **** port 19854:11:  [preauth]
Aug 31 15:44:58 Jimmy sshd[12026]: Disconnected from authenticating user root **** port 19854 [preauth]
Aug 31 15:45:07 Jimmy sshd[11912]: Received disconnect from 81.28.198.29 port 50547:11: disconnected by user
Aug 31 15:45:07 Jimmy sshd[11912]: Disconnected from user my_user 81.28.198.29 port 50547
Aug 31 15:45:07 Jimmy sshd[11910]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user my_user
Aug 31 15:45:07 Jimmy kernel: elogind-daemon[20296]: Removed session c56.
Aug 31 15:45:13 Jimmy sshd[12253]: Accepted publickey for my_user from **** port 50605 ssh2: RSA SHA256:****
Aug 31 15:45:13 Jimmy kernel: elogind-daemon[20296]: Existing logind session ID 1 used by new audit session, ignoring.
Aug 31 15:45:13 Jimmy kernel: elogind-daemon[20296]: New session c57 of user my_user.
Aug 31 15:45:13 Jimmy sshd[12253]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user my_user(uid=1000) by (uid=0)
```

Comment: Try running `ssh` with the "-v" flag to print debugging info. It might print more detail about what is happening. Also check syslog on the server to see if `sshd` is logging anything about the reason that X11 forwarding is failing.

Comment: the last lines of `ssh -vX my_host` are: https://dpaste.com/8SN55L4WZ

Comment: Add more `-v` for more verbosity. Also please do check the server as Kenster suggested. X11 forwarding can be turned off server-side.

Comment: Hi @DanielB and @Kenster I have added more verbose as an eddit to the post. Where does  syslog store the logging of `sshd`?

Comment: @Jimmy2027 The logs will be on the remote server (The host you call "my_host"). They'll probably be in the `/var/logs` directory, but they could be someplace else. The logs are text files. Search them for lines containing the text "sshd". Once you've found the right file, try logging in with ssh as you've been doing, and see what messages are written to the log by sshd.

Comment: I have added the log from the host to the post

Comment: Related: [X11 forwarding request failed on channel 0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38961495/55075)

Answer (score 2):

on the remote server "X11Forwarding" must be set to "yes" in the ssh**d** config (`/etc/ssh/sshd_config`).
you don't have to change ssh client config (/etc/ssh/ssh_config) on your client if you use ssh -X

parameters at the ssh command overide defaults from the ssh client config (/etc/ssh/ssh_config) at your local maschine. pay attention to ssh_config vs. sshd_config -and- client vs. server. sshd could be installed on your local maschine too, but client and server only means: one side starts the concection whereas the other accepts connections (while listing).

after successfully login via ssh the `DISPLAY` variable should be set to something like `localhost:10.0` otherwise X11 forwarding won't work.

hint: if you are connecting to a local server (on LAN) you could skip ssh X11 tunneling and simply do export DISPLAY=<clientIP>:0 on the server and issue an "xhost +<serverIPorFQDN>" on your client. this works by far faster than tunneling X through SSH.